# How can I speed up python's dictionary with Numba

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, numba

I need to store a few cells in array of Boolean values. At first I used numpy, but when arrays started to take a lot of memory, I've got an idea to store non-zero elements in dictionary with tuples as keys (because it's hashable type). For emaxple:
`{(0, 0, 0): True, (1, 2, 3): True}` (This is two cells in "3D array" with indices 0,0,0 and 1,2,3, but number of dimensions are unknown in advance and defined when I run my algorythm).
It helped a lot, because non-zero cells fills just a small part of the array.

For writing and getting values from this dict I need to use loops:

```
def fill_cells(indices, area_dict):
    for i in indices:
        area_dict[tuple(i)] = 1

def get_cells(indices, area_dict):
    n = len(indices)
    out = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.bool)
    for i in range(n):
        out[i] = tuple(indices[i]) in area_dict.keys()
    return out
```

Now I need to speed up it with Numba. Numba doesn't support native Python's dict(), so I used numba.typed.Dict.
The problem is that Numba want to know size of the keys in stage of defining fucntions, so I can't even create the dictionary (length of keys are unknown in advance and defined when I call the function):

```
@njit
def make_dict(n):
    out = {(0,)*n:True}
    return out
```

Numba can't infer the types of dictionary keys correctly and returns the error:

```
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "make_dict" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function mul>) with argument(s) of type(s): (tuple(int64 x 1), int64)
```

If I change n to concrete number in function, it works. I solved it with this trick:

```
n = 10
s = '@njit\ndef make_dict():\n\tout = {(0,)*%s:True}\n\treturn out' % n
exec(s)
```

But I think this is wrong inefficient way. And I steel need to use my fill_cells and get_cells function with @njit decorator, but Numba returns the same error because I'm trying to create tuple from numpy array in this functions.

I understand the fundamental limitations of Numba (and compilation in general), but maybe there is some way to speed up functions, or, maybe you have another solution to my cell-storing problem?

Comment: Have you considered sparse matrices?

Comment: @Marat Yes, I made my own implementation of sparse matrices based on dictionaries of keys (functions fill_cells and get_cells are the part of this implementation). I realized that this is pretty common solution for sparse matrices. The problem is that I need to speed this implementation up. Also, I don't need to do matrix operations on it, just store and get values, maybe it can expand the set of possible solutions.

Comment: native data structures like dicts are pretty inefficient. scipy.sparse provides C implementation, which probably will outperform native structures by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Marat Yes, I found scipy.sparse faster than my solution, but it only works with 2D matrices. I need to work with an arbitrary dimension. I haven't found any solution better than write it by myself and speed it up with Numba (it's what i'm trying to do now and I stacked with problem I described in my question).

Comment: my bad, I completely forgot scipy sparse matrices are 2D only. Tensorflow sparse tensors in eager mode might be a reasonable substitution for arbitrary dimension

Comment: @Marat Good idea, I tried TensorFlow and PyTorch sparse tensors. Both of them don't have feature to get values from indices "directly". I need to find right indices in their "indices" sub-tensor, so it takes a lot of time. My solution is still the fastest way to solve my problem (but not as fast as I need)

Comment: Have you seen https://gist.github.com/sklam/830fe01343ba95828c3b24c391855c86 before? I encountered the same problem when I wanted to use arrays as indices for matrices. It only needs a small adjustment at the top, because dicts have no ndim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Final solution:

The main problem was that Numba need to know length of tuples when defining function that creates it. The trick is to redefine function each time. I needed to generate string with code that defines fucntion and run it with **exec()**:

```
n = 10
s = '@njit\ndef arr_to_tuple(a):\n\treturn (' + ''.join('a[%i],' % i for i in range(n)) + ')'
exec(s)
```

After that I can call **arr_to_tuple(a)** to create tuples that can be uses in another @njit - decorated functions.

For example, creating empty dictionary of tuple keys, that needed to solve the problem:

```
@njit
def make_empty_dict():
    tpl = arr_to_tuple(np.array([0]*5))
    out = {tpl:True}
    del out[tpl]
    return out
```

I write one element in dictionary because it's one of the ways of Numba to infer types.

Also, I need to use my **fill_cells** and **get_cells**  function that described in the question. This is how I've rewritten them with Numba:

Writing elements. Just changed tuple() to arr_to_tuple():

```
@njit
def fill_cells_nb(indices, area_dict):
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        area_dict[arr_to_tuple(indices[i])] = True
```

Getting elements from dictionary required a bit of creepy code:

```
@njit
def get_cells_nb(indices, area_dict):
    n = len(indices)
    out = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(n):
        new_len = len(area_dict)
        tpl = arr_to_tuple(indices[i])
        area_dict[tpl] = True
        old_len = len(area_dict)
        if new_len == old_len:
            out[i] = True
        else:
            del area_dict[tpl]
    return out
```

My version of Numba (0.46) doesn't support .contains (in) operator and try-except construction. If you have version that supports it you can write more "regular" solution for it.

So when I want to check if the element with some index exist in dictionary I memorize the length of it, then I write  in dictionary something with mentioned index. If length changed I conclude that the element wasn't exist. Otherwise the element exists. Looks like very slow solution, but it's not.

### Speed test:

Solutions work surprisingly fast. I tested it with %timeit in comparison to native-Python optimized code:

1. **arr_to_tuple()** 5 times faster than regular **tuple()** function
2. **get_cells with numba** 3 times faster for one element and 40 times faster for big arrays of elements compare to **native-Python written get_cells**
3. **fill_cells with numba** 4 times faster for one element and 40 times faster for big arrays of elements compare to **native-Python written fill_cells**

Comment: Did you compare the performance with a typed List? It seems you don't really need to store "True", since that's already implied by storing the indices. You could also consider writing an `unravel_index` and  `ravel_multi_index` function, similar to Numpy, that makes the index to store always 1D.

Comment: @RutgerKassies I compared it after your comment. Working with typed list is significantly slower because list's elements need to be checked in loop to get checked. The time of execution of function depends from size of list, contrary with Dict that has constant time because of hashing keys.

Comment: By the way, I figured out that for such a problem it may be reasonable (faster) to use native Python hash() function and use it in loop instead of ravel_multi_index. This loops can be decorated with @njit without significant changing of code.